# M2: Custom shipping for specyfic group

Tags: magento2

We have created 4 customers groups:

1) group1

2) group2

3) group3

4) group4

And we use custom shipping:

https://www.mageplaza.com/devdocs/magento-2-create-shipping-method/

Our website required login. How to display this custom shipping only for group1 and group2 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In `app/code/Mageplaza/Simpleshipping/Model/Carrier/Shipping.php` you have method `collectRates` in which you have:

```
if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active')) {
  return false;
}
```

You can add something like `if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') && customer_group != group3)`
But you have to get customer information in `Shipping.php`.

**EDIT:**

```
<?php
namespace Mageplaza\Simpleshipping\Model\Carrier;

use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateRequest;
use Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result;

class Shipping extends \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\AbstractCarrier implements
    \Magento\Shipping\Model\Carrier\CarrierInterface
{
    /**
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_code = 'simpleshipping';

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory
     */
    protected $_rateResultFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory
     */
    protected $_rateMethodFactory;
    protected $groupRepository;
protected $_customerSession;

    /**
     * Shipping constructor.
     *
     * @param \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface          $scopeConfig
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory  $rateErrorFactory
     * @param \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface                                    $logger
     * @param \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory                  $rateResultFactory
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory
     * @param array                                                       $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\Config\ScopeConfigInterface $scopeConfig,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\ErrorFactory $rateErrorFactory,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\GroupRepositoryInterface $groupRepository,
\Magento\Customer\Model\Session $customerSession,
        \Psr\Log\LoggerInterface $logger,
        \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\ResultFactory $rateResultFactory,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\MethodFactory $rateMethodFactory,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_rateResultFactory = $rateResultFactory;
        $this->_rateMethodFactory = $rateMethodFactory;
        $this->groupRepository = $groupRepository;
        $this->_customerSession = $customerSession;
        parent::__construct($scopeConfig, $rateErrorFactory, $logger, $data);
    }

    /**
     * get allowed methods
     * @return array
     */
    public function getAllowedMethods()
    {
        return [$this->_code => $this->getConfigData('name')];
    }

    /**
     * @return float
     */
    private function getShippingPrice()
    {
        $configPrice = $this->getConfigData('price');

        $shippingPrice = $this->getFinalPriceWithHandlingFee($configPrice);

        return $shippingPrice;
    }

    /**
     * @param RateRequest $request
     * @return bool|Result
     */
    public function collectRates(RateRequest $request)
    {
      $customerGroupId = $this->_customerSession->getCustomer()->getGroupId();
        $group = $this->groupRepository->getById($customerGroupId);
        $this->_logger->info($group->getCode());

if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') || ($group->getCode() == "Wholesale User UE-VAT") || ($group->getCode() == "Wholesale User")){
return false;
}

        /** @var \Magento\Shipping\Model\Rate\Result $result */
        $result = $this->_rateResultFactory->create();

        /** @var \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\RateResult\Method $method */
        $method = $this->_rateMethodFactory->create();

        $method->setCarrier($this->_code);
        $method->setCarrierTitle($this->getConfigData('title'));

        $method->setMethod($this->_code);
        $method->setMethodTitle($this->getConfigData('name'));

        $amount = $this->getShippingPrice();

        $method->setPrice($amount);
        $method->setCost($amount);

        $result->append($method);

        return $result;
    }
}
```

After this changes do `setup:di:compile, setup:upgrade`. in var/log/system.log you will get info about group.
in method collectRates at the beginning you have variable `$group` which will show you the customer group name. Then you have to put this var in if statment.

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Can you help us develop the code and get information about the customer? or Should I ask a question in the next topic?

Comment: check my update

Comment: Thank you for update, where in this code I can define: show this shipping method for customer group: I want to show this method for this both group:  https://prnt.sc/stjkjc

Comment: I edited my answer. Copy this code and put it in shipping.php file from mageplaza module. When you are on checkout chec system.log file if there is info about group.

Comment: I updated this file but currently I do not see any shipping method. In log file I see : [2020-06-04 09:24:04] main.INFO: Consumer "async.operations.all" skipped as required connection "amqp" is not configured. Unknown connection name amqp [] []

Comment: exception.log: [2020-06-04 09:23:45] main.CRITICAL: Report ID: webapi-5ed8bda154f26; Message: Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\Customer\Model\Data\Group could not be converted to string in /home/domain/domains/catalog.domain.com/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.php on line 329 {"exception":"[object] (Exception(code: 0): Report ID: webapi-5ed8bda154f26; Message: Recoverable Error: Object of class Magento\\Customer\\Model\\Data\\Group could not be converted to string in /home/domain/domains/catalog.domain.com/public_html/vendor/monolog/monolog/src/Monolog/Logger.

Comment: in collectRates replace $this->_logger->info($group); with $this->_logger->info($group->getCode()); and clear cache and check results

Comment: I get it. Here is log: [2020-06-04 10:02:14] main.INFO: Wholesale User UE-VAT [] []

Comment: so here I add rule:   if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') && customer_group != Wholesale User UE-VAT){
            return false;
        }

Comment: I want add one more group for hide this shipping: Wholesale User so I want hide for Wholesale User UE-VAT & Wholesale User. How can I add here rule for this both group?

Comment: edit: I think I do something wrong in this code because now checkout not load: if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') && customer_group != Wholesale User UE-VAT){ return false; }

Comment: if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') && (customer_group != "Wholesale User UE-VAT") && (customer_group != "Wholesale User")){ return false; } 
You forgot quotes

Comment: once again thank you for you support and assist. But we update code and now I do not see any issue. But still this shipping method is visible on checkout. Here you see my customer group:  https://prnt.sc/stlt18 and  shipping drop service (custom shipping mageplaza) should be hidden but still  is visible:  https://prnt.sc/stlshc

Comment: in this if statment replace customer_group with $group->getCode()
This should work :D

Comment: So now we have code:   if (!$this->getConfigFlag('active') && ($group->getCode() != "Wholesale User UE-VAT") && ($group->getCode() != "Wholesale User")){
            return false;
        }

Comment: Now I run s:up, cf, deploy, s:di:co  and still  is visible this shipping method ;(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/108877/discussion-between-sebastiant-and-sylvester).